# Centering images horizontally inside a container with smaller size

Tags: html, css

I have a layout problem where I want to center images horizontally that is bigger than the container they are in. the container size is 800px and the images are 1200px.
when I use regular `max-width` and `margin:0 auto` it results in something like this. how can I make the images centered horizontally in this layout **and keep the image size to 1200px**
[image]

But I want it to be something like this:
[image]

Comment: Post your [mcve] please

Comment: So you want them to be visible outside their container, is that correct, and for each image to keep its natural width and height? Without seeing your HTML structure any answer will just be a guess I'm afraid.

Comment: If the img is a child of the 800px container then set its margin-left to -200px

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply `display: block;` `and` position:relative;`to your image to make it possible to move it, then`left: 50%;`(which moves its left side to the center of the parent container) and`transform: translateY(-50%);`, which moves it to the left by 50% of its own width.

All this together will center it horizontally the way you asked for.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you just change the HTML with `<div>` separator, it will make sense for the image width will follow its parents instead of the paragraph's parent.

---

Before:

```css
.center {
  margin: auto;
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="center">
  <p>div in window center</p>
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/1200/800" />
  <p>div in window center</p>
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/1200/800" />
</div>
```

---

After (*run this snippet only on full page version*):

```css
.center {
  margin: auto;
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="center">
  <p>div in window center</p>
</div>

<div>
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/1200/800" />
</div>

<div class="center">
  <p>div in window center</p>
</div>

<div>
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/1200/800" />
</div>
```

Comment: width:100%; made it fit the container. which I don't want. I wanted to be sill 1400px.

Answer (score -2):

`width: 100%` should work perfectly. It will be easier to answer if you share your code.

Comment: Updated the question. I don't want it to become the same width as the container. i want to keep it as 1200px.